# ActionController::UnknownFormat in HelpController#about

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

as a Ruby newbie I am still getting to grips with the language. I have created a broadcast controller for a simple database that is already being used in production. However, I am getting the above mentioned error. Below is the code I have used:

**show.html.erb**

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

   <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_broadcast_path(@broadcast) %> |
   <%= link_to 'Back', broadcasts_path %>
```

**Index.html.erb**
[index.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrPan.png)

**broadcasts_controller.rb**
[boradcast controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwihW.png)

**help controller**

```
  class HelpController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  def about
  #render text: "Hello"
  end
```

end

I am not sure if I am missing any files or configs, I will add them in the comments if need be. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Incoming requests may use headers or parameters to indicate to Rails what format, called "MIME type", the response should have. For instance, a typical GET request from entering a URL into your browser will ask for an HTML (or default) response. Other types of common responses return JSON or XML.

In your case your "about" action does not have any explicit responders, and because of that Rails can't match the requested format (which is what the error message is trying to convey). You will probably just want to add an HTML template `app/views/help/about.html.erb` with your content. Rails should identify the HTML template and handle things from there.

#### More info

In Rails you need to respond with a specific format, and it is easy to setup your controller actions to handle a variety of formats.

Here is a snippet you might find in a controller which can respond in 3 different ways.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render "foo" } # renders foo.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @foo }
  format.xml { render xml: @foo }
end
```

You can see more examples and deeper explanations in the documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/MimeResponds.html).

ActiveRecord helps because it comes with serializers out of the box which can create JSON and XML representations of your objects.